# External display is jittery and laggy @ 4k 60hz while playing video,editing or using CAD sotware? How do i solve it?

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, performance, 4k-resolution

**LAPTOP SPECS-**

- Lenovo 720s fhd native display.
- List item
- i7 8th gen
- 8gb RAM, SSD
- Intel integrated 620 UHD graphics driver.
  windows 10

High-quality type c to HDMI 2.0 wire

Monitor, https://www.philips.com.my/c-p/276E8VJSB_69/4k-ultra-hd-lcd-monitor

ISSUE- video and display is crip and nice, but its a bit slow and jittery and laggy. the input lag is like 0.5 sec.

what should I do? and how do I solve this problem?
I am thinking this is due to my shitty graphics driver?

Answer (score 0):

A puzzle since it look like you have covered all the bases.  I have a surface pro 6 with lower cpu specs but the same 620 UHD video and using a mini-dvi port and it works with the drivers on the original machine, flawlessly.  In the past I have found the weak point in these display from ultraportable is >50% of the time the cable as long as the ultraportable vendor design allows 4k external display, as mine and yours does.  In the first instance I would try another cable (from a different vendor) since HDMI cables can vary a lot in quality; even from the same vendor.  You could also try a cable to the displayport on the display - these are much more consistent in quality.  If those don't work then I suspect you will need to contact Lenovo (after trying a different display) and perhaps Phillips (after trying a different monitor).